# PostgreSQL: starting a sequence at MAX(the_column)+1

Tags: postgresql, sequence, unique-constraint

I want to add a sequence to a column that might already have data, so I'm trying to start it beyond whatever's already there. Assuming there already is data, I would like to have done it this way:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence MINVALUE 1000000 START
    (SELECT MAX(id_column) FROM my_table) OWNED BY my_table.id_column;
```

but it keeps dying at `(` claiming syntax error. It's like the start value has to be cold hard numbers--nothing symbolic.

Of course, an even better solution would be if the sequence could be intelligent enough to avoid duplicate values, since `id_column` has a unique constraint on it--that's why I'm doing this. But from what I can tell, that's not possible.

I also tried skipping the `START` and then doing:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE my_sequence RESTART WITH (SELECT max(id_column)+1 FROM my_table);
```

but, again, it doesn't seem like to symbolic start values.

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4 but some of our customers are using stuff as primitive as 8.3.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can't specify a dynamic value for the start value.

But you can set the value once the sequence is created:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence MINVALUE 1000000 OWNED BY my_table.id_column;
select setval('my_sequence',  (SELECT MAX(id_column) FROM my_table));
```

Comment: Amazing... I was about to edit this to add `MAX(id_column)+1` so that the sequence would start beyond the max, but when I tested it, it really did start from 1 after the largest `id_column`! So I guess `START 1000000` really means "start at 1000001".

Comment: I can't confirm what Opux said; I had to do MAX + 1.

Comment: @Noumenon that likely had to do with the sequence's `is_called` column. If `false`, the next call to `nextval()` returns the current value of the sequence. If `is_called` is `true`, the sequence will be incremented before returning the new value. When calling `setval`, you can specify a third param to set `is_called`, but it defaults to `true`. In other words, `setval('my_sequence', (SELECT MAX(id_column) FROM my_table));` should always cause future defaults to "start from 1 after the largest `id_column`". This seems true since v7.2. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score 8):

You can restore you sequence by request:

```sql
select setval('my_sequence', (SELECT MAX(id_column) FROM my_table));
```

Applicable for Postgres 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

Just because I was struggling with a slight variation in use case to the accepted answers here and experiencing an error telling me that `setval` did not exist, thought I'd share in case others had the same.

I needed to set the value of my sequence to the max value in an `id` column, but I also wanted to combine that with a default starting value if there were no rows.

To do this I used `coalesce` combined with `max` like this:

```
select setval('sequence', cast((select coalesce(max(id),1) from table) as bigint));
```

The catch here was using `cast` with the select, without that, you get an error something like:

```
ERROR:  function setval(unknown, double precision) does not exist
LINE 1: select setval('sequence', (select coalesce(MAX(i...

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```